# AngularJS (Loading JSON with custom Service)

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to built a service for loading json files. What am I doing wrong?

The Service

```
app.service("jsonService", function ($http, $q)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('./assets/json/home.json').then(function (data)
    {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getHomeItems = function ()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

My Controller

```
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, jsonService) {

    var promise = jsonService.getHomeItems();
    promise.then(function (data)
    {
        $scope.home_items = data;
        console.log($scope.home_items);
    });

});
```

Console Error: $scope is not defined

Comment: In which line are you getting ~ Console Error: $scope is not defined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use $http to load a JSON file directly, you shouldn't need this service. Methods of $http return a promise, and the default response handler parses JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Your service should be:

```
app.service("jsonService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("./assets/json/home.json").then(function (data)
    {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getHomeItems = function ()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

And your Controller:

```
app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "jsonService", function ($scope, jsonService)
{
    var promise = jsonService.getHomeItems();
    promise.then(function (data)
    {
        $scope.home_items = data;
        console.log($scope.home_items);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the HTML, which you did not provide, I reckon you may not have injected the $scope into your controller constructor:

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function ($scope,  jsonService) {
    ...
}]);
```

Theoretically, AngularJS should be able to infer the dependency from the variable name, but according to the official documentation there are circumstances where this does not work and the practice of not explicitly injecting dependencies is discouraged.
So you may want to try explicit injection (as shown above).

See the examples on the official docs here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

and here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

You are have a common anti-pattern where you are unwrapping the promise returned by $http and then re-wrapping the data in a promise. This is unnecessary, just return the promise returned by $http.

```
this.getHomeItems = function () {
    return $http.get("./assets/json/home.json");
}
```